# Woocommerce new order email not sent when customer email is wrong

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

I discovered strange issue. 
In WooCommerce - when a customer enters wrong email address the new order email to admin/shop manager does not send. The order is placed and the transaction is successful but there is no notification.

Can anyone tell why is that and if there is any workaround or fix.

Comment: Is the email address in a valid format, but referencing a non-existent domain/mailbox? Or is it an invalid format? If there's an example you can share, I'll try to reproduce the problem. 

Might also be worth checking for any email/SMTP plugins that might be trying to validate the address and throwing an exception that disrupts the email flow.

Comment: The email was basically: something@something.coma. There was 'a' added at the end of the domain. Once I have removed it, the email resent with no problems. I know that the email will obviously not sent to the customer as its not correct but why the store is not receiving a new order email - the order is placed and paid for...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tested this on a no-additional-plugins install, and the new order email to the admin/shop-manager went out. So it might be something specific to your install.

Comment: I am also getting this issue, I am using wp mail SMTP plugin and gmail SMTP integration. All other mails are working fine. Only the new order mail with an invalid cuatomer email(in a valid mail format) is not getting in admin side.